# mean stack with angular 5 and passportjs

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, mean-stack

how I can  make auth in a mean stack with angular 5 and node js and passport js?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find it in youtube... 
[Traversy course for it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1ktxiqyiLA&list=PLillGF-RfqbbqvbObyE7CldS5-trkefnB)

Comment: i am asking about mean stack with angular 5?

Comment: He has a course using Angular too. Its a good channel to start